# How to print a variable which is created using for loops

Tags: python, for-loop, printing

I am trying to automate some of the manual tasks using python3 and I am not sure how to print a variable. I know I can use print(f"https://{ip1}", but I am trying to solve this problem using "for loops"

Here is the part of the code.

```
......
def hostFile():
    hostConf = (projdateprojname[9:])
    print("\n\tEnter legacy host IP")
    ip1  = input(prompt)
    print("\n\tEnter legacy guest IP")
    ip2  = input(prompt)
    print("\n\tEnter legacy host IP")
    ip3  = input(prompt)
    print("\n\tEnter legacy guest IP")
    ip4  = input(prompt)
    print(f"\n[{hostConf}-1]")
    print(f"{ip1}")
    print(f"{ip2}")
    print(f"{ip3}")
    print(f"{ip4}")
    for i in range(1, 5):
        listofurl =  ("ip" + str(i))
        print(f"https://{listofurl}")
```

```
    Script output for the last part:
    https://ip1
    https://ip2
    https://ip3
    https://ip4


    I am expecting to see, for example 
    https://10.1.1.199
    https://10.1.1.200
    https://10.1.1.201
    https://10.1.1.202
```

Comment: You could change your `ip` variables into a list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create variable variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables)

Answer (score 0):

I see what you were trying to do, just one adjustment change

```
listofurl =  ("ip" + str(i))
```

to

```
listofurl =  (locals()["ip" + str(i)])
```

`locals()` return a dictionary`{}` of variables in the current scope, `["ip" + str(i)]` gets translated to `["ip<i>"]` where`i` changes value during each phase of the loop

Comment: Hi Dave, I had to go through the concept of locals() few time. I wasn't aware of that function. I really appreciate your help. Thanks and much obliged.